# Parsing XML Data using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, sql-server-2019

I am attempting to parse XML data using SQL Server 2019.

I have the following dataset:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.test.report/Reported_Time_Blocks_for_a_Worker_s__-_Test_Worked_Hours_-_Copy">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:Employee_ID>111111</wd:Employee_ID>
            <wd:Legal_Name_-_First_Name>TestFirstName</wd:Legal_Name_-_First_Name>
            <wd:Legal_Name_-_Last_Name>TestLastName</wd:Legal_Name_-_Last_Name>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Employee_Type wd:Descriptor="Property">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_Type_ID">Regular</wd:ID>
        </wd:Employee_Type>
        <wd:Pay_Rate_Type wd:Descriptor="Salary">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Pay_Rate_Type_ID">Salary</wd:ID>
        </wd:Pay_Rate_Type>
        <wd:Pay_Rate>0</wd:Pay_Rate>
        <wd:Home_Cost_Center wd:Descriptor="CC0001 Test Property">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">CC0001</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID">CC0001</wd:ID>
        </wd:Home_Cost_Center>
        <wd:Home_Subarea wd:Descriptor="HS001 Test Home">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">HS001</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">HS001</wd:ID>
        </wd:Home_Subarea>
        <wd:Home_Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="Test Job Title">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">6db2e1cea51601ac7fdd4d733e001646</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">100000001</wd:ID>
        </wd:Home_Job_Profile>
        <wd:Reported_Date>2022-04-11-07:00</wd:Reported_Date>
        <wd:Reported_Quantity>8</wd:Reported_Quantity>
        <wd:Time_Entry_Code wd:Descriptor="Worked Time (Hours Only)">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Code_Reference_ID">Worked_Time_Hours_Only_Time_Code</wd:ID>
        </wd:Time_Entry_Code>
        <wd:Calculation_Tags wd:Descriptor="Regular">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Calculation_Tag_ID">Regular</wd:ID>
        </wd:Calculation_Tags>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
```

I know how to get some of the data, but I can't figure out how to work with the multiple row groups.

I have this query that pulls the Employee_ID, Legal_Name_-*First_Name, and Legal_Name*-_Last_Name, but I can't figure out how to also pull the Employee_Type, Pay_Rate_Type, etc. with it:

```
DECLARE @XML XML
    SET @XML = ( SELECT XMLData FROM #XML )

DECLARE @XML XML
    SET @XML = ( SELECT XMLData FROM #XML )

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 'urn:com.test.report/Reported_Time_Blocks_for_a_Worker_s__-_Test_Worked_Hours_-_Copy' AS wd )
SELECT  EmployeeId = Data.Col.value( 'wd:Employee_ID[1]', 'VARCHAR(12)' ),
        FirstName = Data.Col.value( 'wd:Legal_Name_-_First_Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' ),
        LastName = Data.Col.value( 'wd:Legal_Name_-_Last_Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )
    --INTO #EmployeeInformation
    FROM @XML.nodes( 'wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Worker_group' ) Data( Col )
```

I am essentially trying to pull the following data from the XML above:

| Employee_ID | Legal_Name_-_First_Name | Legal_Name_-_Last_Name | Employee_Type_ID | Pay_Rate_Type_ID | Pay_Rate | Cost_Center_Reference_ID | Reported_Date | Reported_Quantity | Home_Job_Profile_Descriptor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | TestFirstName | TestLastName | Regular | Salary | 0 | CC0001 | 2022-04-11-07:00 | 8 | Test Job Title |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Creating the table/Insert statements is a little tricky with it being sensitive data. I gave logic/code attempts, I gave the desired out, and the SQL version is in the tag.

Comment: The idea of the minimal reproducible example is very simple. You copy it as-is to SSMS, execute it, and it runs there. Same for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

You may need to adjust data types.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.test.report/Reported_Time_Blocks_for_a_Worker_s__-_Test_Worked_Hours_-_Copy">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_group>
            <wd:Employee_ID>111111</wd:Employee_ID>
            <wd:Legal_Name_-_First_Name>TestFirstName</wd:Legal_Name_-_First_Name>
            <wd:Legal_Name_-_Last_Name>TestLastName</wd:Legal_Name_-_Last_Name>
        </wd:Worker_group>
        <wd:Employee_Type wd:Descriptor="Property">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_Type_ID">Regular</wd:ID>
        </wd:Employee_Type>
        <wd:Pay_Rate_Type wd:Descriptor="Salary">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Pay_Rate_Type_ID">Salary</wd:ID>
        </wd:Pay_Rate_Type>
        <wd:Pay_Rate>0</wd:Pay_Rate>
        <wd:Home_Cost_Center wd:Descriptor="CC0001 Test Property">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">CC0001</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID">CC0001</wd:ID>
        </wd:Home_Cost_Center>
        <wd:Home_Subarea wd:Descriptor="HS001 Test Home">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">HS001</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Organization_Reference_ID">HS001</wd:ID>
        </wd:Home_Subarea>
        <wd:Home_Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="Test Job Title">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">6db2e1cea51601ac7fdd4d733e001646</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">100000001</wd:ID>
        </wd:Home_Job_Profile>
        <wd:Reported_Date>2022-04-11-07:00</wd:Reported_Date>
        <wd:Reported_Quantity>8</wd:Reported_Quantity>
        <wd:Time_Entry_Code wd:Descriptor="Worked Time (Hours Only)">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Code_Reference_ID">Worked_Time_Hours_Only_Time_Code</wd:ID>
        </wd:Time_Entry_Code>
        <wd:Calculation_Tags wd:Descriptor="Regular">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Calculation_Tag_ID">Regular</wd:ID>
        </wd:Calculation_Tags>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:com.test.report/Reported_Time_Blocks_for_a_Worker_s__-_Test_Worked_Hours_-_Copy')
SELECT EmployeeId = c.value('(Worker_group/Employee_ID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(12)' )
    , FirstName = c.value('(Worker_group/Legal_Name_-_First_Name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )
    , LastName = c.value('(Worker_group/Legal_Name_-_Last_Name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )
    , Employee_Type_ID = c.value('(Employee_Type/ID[@*:type="Employee_Type_ID"]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )
    , Pay_Rate_Type_ID = c.value('(Pay_Rate_Type/ID[@*:type="Pay_Rate_Type_ID"]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )
    , Pay_Rate = c.value('(Pay_Rate/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )
    , Cost_Center_Reference_ID = c.value('(Home_Cost_Center/ID[@*:type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID"]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )
    , Reported_Date = c.value('(Reported_Date/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )
    , Reported_Quantity = c.value('(Reported_Quantity/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )
    , Home_Job_Profile_Descriptor = c.value('(Home_Job_Profile/@*:Descriptor)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' )
FROM @XML.nodes('/Report_Data/Report_Entry') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+------------------+----------+--------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| EmployeeId |   FirstName   |   LastName   | Employee_Type_ID | Pay_Rate_Type_ID | Pay_Rate | Cost_Center_Reference_ID |  Reported_Date   | Reported_Quantity | Home_Job_Profile_Descriptor |
+------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+------------------+----------+--------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
|     111111 | TestFirstName | TestLastName | Regular          | Salary           |        0 | CC0001                   | 2022-04-11-07:00 |                 8 | Test Job Title              |
+------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+------------------+----------+--------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! Should have asked originally, but would you have an idea on how to pull the Descriptor? Specifically the Home_Job_Profile:

<wd:Home_Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="Test Job Title">

Comment: Please update your desired output in the original question.

Comment: Added, I also made a dbfiddle, maybe it helps? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3dff590ba4c29aed9d8718b8fb73791d

Comment: Done. Check it out.

Comment: Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0